# Open a c++ application installed on computer with a custom url in browser

Tags: c++, google-chrome, web, url, browser

I would like to make a c++ app that opens when a URL is open in the browser.
It's like the "YT2MP3 Converter" that opens the "yt2mp3://link-of-video"(yt2mp3:// not http://) in the browser and it opens the app installed on the computer. How can i do this in c++?
I want to open the app from a chrome extension.
It's like "On click, open the cappurl://current-page-location"

Comment: That's not really related to `c++` because it's about how to configure your webbrowser.

Comment: Yes, thank you all